# When I try to run ipython on powershell, I get the error "Failed to create process"

Tags: python-2.7, ipython

I installed pythonxy (2.7.9), but when I try to run ipython from windows powershell, I get an error "failed to create process." What steps can I take to solve this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: Does it work in a regular command prompt (not PowerShell)?

Comment: I solved the problem by completely removing python from my computer and reinstalling

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Windows after I had 2 version of Python installed. Even after I uninstalled one version of Python through Control Panel, the folder C:\Python2.7 still existed. After I deleted this folder manually, ipython started work normally.

Answer (score 1):

Go to cmd and type where iPython. if it results in two locations, delete one and proceed with other. Usually this happens when you have installed Anaconda distribution after installing python in your local system. Deleting python version locally would be a better solution. And then go to the root folder, (Ex: C:\Users\Desktop\new_folder), by holding shift, click right button and go to open command prompt here. Type iPython. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also rename folders, for example C:\Python27_ , so that they are not found. This way you don't have to delete your libraries! Then you remove the underscore depending on the project you are working in.

Make sure you have the relevant directories in the path, otherwise the version you do want won't be found at all.

Sorry of this sounds silly, but after painlessly failing to setup virtualenv in Windows, this solution comes in handy for having multiple Python installations.